# Change price configurable product

Tags: magento-2.1

I have Magento 2.1.2. The store have years working but last week when I create a configurable product, in the frontend show select to change options but the price not change:

[image]

[image]

Change the select but not price. When add the product to cart the price is correct but I don't know why not change the price

Comment: Check your browser console for error log.May issue in some javascript code

Comment: Anything show. And Magento logs too

Answer (score 0):

It must be be due to some conflicts under the Catalog_product_view.xml layout file in your theme/child theme, remove any customization and than recheck